# Does anyone have the dance steps for the Lashon Horah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Years ago, I attended an Israeli dance program at [Camp Blue Star](http://findyoursummer.org/programs/blue-star-camps) which had a 3 day Israeli dance program where they brought in various Israeli dance teachers who taught us some of the new and reviewed older Israeli dances. I learned that there are several variations on the popular Israeli dance called the "Hora."

The hora is a "circle dance" (as opposed to couples dances or line dances, etc.) However, there are numerous variations to the hora and they all have names such as "The Yemenite Hora", "The Galil Hora" , "The Sprinkler Hora" (In Hebrew known as "הורה ממטרה" for those dancers, around.) I used to have a book that described many of these dances.

One Hora, in particular, I couldn't locate. It is called the Lashon Horah. I assume that this is a dance that has something to do with the tongue, in some way.

Can anyone describe, briefly, who may have choreographed the Lashon Horah and when, as well, as perhaps, give a brief description of what it looks like? I'd be especially curious as to why this horah was named the Lashon Horah.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You couldn't find it because it is forbidden to be danced - or even spoken (about)!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Speaking ABOUT Lashon Horah is not Lashon Horah.

Comment: @mevaqesh You must be desperate for points :-) It's tough not too make it correct when there's no competition. Thanks for the entry, and more so, for the educational info. Happy Cow's Shabbat.

Comment: I actually post those comments even when I'm not one if the answers. There's something glaringly unfinished about a question with no accepted answer. I also like the points :)

Comment: You may want to suggest this on the "meta" site. I.e. add a feature for the system to automatically initiate an entry in the O.P.'s "inbox" to accept an answer on a question that has remained idle for some extensive time (say, a month, or whatever you think is reasonable.) Sometimes, questions stay idle for a year, and then new answers come in. I've had that with several of my questions. I'm not sure that would qualify for such a request, but you can mull that over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike some other dance styles, [the Lashon Horah has no set rules or steps](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76871/8775). Rather, any style or step which is meant to hurt others, is included.   [It does not appear that use of the tongue is necessary (See 16. דרך ההבעה)](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/sinay/allashon1-4.htm)(1).

I assume that an example would be deliberately stepping on others' feet.

As far as we know, this style goes back to antiquity. Many assume that it is named after the tongue, since the tongue is classically used to hurt others. (Think of how many times you have been hurt by others, and how many times involved speech rather than say, blunt objects).

Therefore, this deliberately violent hora dance, is named after the tongue.

---

(1) 
 דרך ההבעה
1. סיפור לשון הרע אסור בין שדרך הבעתו בעל-פה בין שהיא בכתב, ובין בכל צורה אחרת, בין בצורה שלימה בין דרך רמז.