# Is it considered listening to loshon hora to look at a biography of a Jewish person on Wikipedia?

Tags: halacha, speech-talking, chofetz-chaim, loshon-hara

Is this considered listening to loshon hora? Let’s say a celebrity happens to be Jewish and Wikipedia has a page about them. Is it mutar to read it if it has negative things said?

Comment: Or this? [Reading Lashon Harah Online](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94481/6592)

Comment: If that will change the way you personally relate to that person then it is *lashon ha'ra*.