# What responsibility does a current tenant have to warn a prospective future tenant?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, real-estate, rental

A tenant is leaving the property he had rented at the end of the contract period. The landlord has arranged for prospective future tenants to view the property, while the current tenant is still there.

The current tenant is aware of various issues / problems with the property and/or the behavior of the landlord.

**What, if anything, may or should the current tenant say to prospective tenants?**

Does it make a difference whether the current tenant is volunteering the information, as opposed to answering questions that the prospective tenant has asked?

Possible angles to explore could include the prohibition against [standing by when another is at risk of harm](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.16?lang=bi) versus the prohibition against [slander](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.16?lang=bi).

If it makes a difference, assume all parties are observant Jews.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43709/5514

Comment: Do you specifically ask about a tenant being still under a contract? Like a customer that stands inside a store talking to another potential customer? Do you think his contract limits his actions?

Comment: @AlBerko I hadn't really considered the angle of the contract between landlord and current tenant. If you think that that makes a difference to the answer then feel free to factor that in

Comment: The answer surely has to include a difference between objective issues (the heating is broken) and subjective issues (the landlord is ___________.) and borderline objective/subjective issues (the building is noisy)

Comment: Another possible factor: Whether it's something the prospective tenant should reasonably know to look for on his own (i.e. if there's a giant hole in the ceiling and the tenant doesn't look up prior to signing the lease, it might not be your obligation to let him know).